# How to define log-count ratio for multiclass text dataset (fastai)?

Tags: nlp, text-classification, naivebayes, fast-ai

I am trying to follow Rachel Thomas path of sentiment classification with Naive Bayes. In the video she uses a binary dataset (pos. and neg. movie reviews). When it comes to apply Naive Bayes, [this is what she does](https://youtu.be/dt7sArnLo1g?t=1185):

**Defintion:** log-count ratio r for each word f:

```
r = log (ratio of feature f in positive documents) / (ratio of feature f in negative documents)
```

where ratio of feature $f$ in positive documents is the number of times a positive document has a feature divided by the number of positive documents.

```
p1 = np.squeeze(np.asarray(x[y.items==positive].sum(0)))
p0 = np.squeeze(np.asarray(x[y.items==negative].sum(0)))

pr1 = (p1+1) / ((y.items==positive).sum() + 1)
pr0 = (p0+1) / ((y.items==negative).sum() + 1)

r = np.log(pr1/pr0)
```

--> it is very simple to apply the log-count-ratio to a dataset with 2 labels!

**Problem:** 
My dataset is not binary! Lets assume I have 5 labels: label_1,...,label_5

How do I get the log-count ratio r for multilabel dataset?

**My approach:**

```
p4 = np.squeeze(np.asarray(x[y.items==label_5].sum(0)))
p3 = np.squeeze(np.asarray(x[y.items==label_4].sum(0)))
p2 = np.squeeze(np.asarray(x[y.items==label_3].sum(0)))
p1 = np.squeeze(np.asarray(x[y.items==label_2].sum(0)))
p0 = np.squeeze(np.asarray(x[y.items==label_1].sum(0)))

log-count-ratio:
pr1 = (p1+1) / ((y.items==label_2).sum() + 1)
pr1_not = (p1+1) / ((y.items!=label_2).sum() + 1)
r_1 = np.log(pr1/pr1_not)

log-count-ratio:
pr2 = (p2+1) / ((y.items==label_3).sum() + 1)
pr2_not = (p2+1) / ((y.items!=label_3).sum() + 1)
r_2 = np.log(pr2/pr2_not)
...
```

Is this correct? Does it mean I get multiple ratios?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is correct. The “negative class” is basically all the classes but the one you are considering. So yes, you will get multiple ratios (as many as number of classes you have).

Answer (score 0):

From https://marvinlsj.github.io/2018/11/23/NBSVM%20for%20sentiment%20and%20topic%20classification/
, the log-count-ratio is derived from Posterior prob ratio which is good for comparing 2 classes to get insight into which is the most probable. I guess you're trying to do one-vs-one method for multi-class problem. This will end up with 5x4/2=10 pairs of ratios for classification. If you'd like to do classification only, we normally compute Posterior prob for each class and select the best. So in your case, you just select the best from sum(log(p1)), sum(log(p2)), ..., sum(log(p5)).